# SSL Connection Issue Between Blazor App and Envoy Gateway

Tags: asp.net, docker, ssl, docker-compose

I have a problem in my project that I can't request from my blazor app to envoy.

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  envoygateway:
    container_name: envoygateway
    ports:
      - 9902:9902
      - 10001:10000
    volumes:
      - ./Envoy/envoy.yaml:/etc/envoy/envoy.yaml
    networks:
      - test-net-1
    depends_on:
      - firstapi
      - secondapi
### First API Reservation ###
  firstapi:
    container_name: firstapi
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - "ConnectionStrings__default=Server=reservationdb,1433;Database=ReservationDb;User=sa;Password=Pa4sword!;TrustServerCertificate=True;"
    ports:
      - "5010:80"
      - "5011:443"
    depends_on:
      - reservationdb
      - rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
    networks:
      - test-net-1

### ReservationDB ###
  reservationdb:
    container_name: reservationdb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - reservationdb:/var/lib/mssql
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    networks:
      - test-net-1

### Second API Email ###
  secondapi:
    container_name: secondapi
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "5020:80"
      - "5021:443"
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
    networks:
      - test-net-1
### RabbiqMQ ###
  rabbitmq:
    container_name: rabbitmq
    environment:
      - "RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest"
      - "RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest"
    ports:
        - 5672:5672
        - 15672:15672
    volumes:
        - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
        - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/log/:/var/log/rabbitmq
    networks:
        - test-net-1
  web:
    container_name: web
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - GatewayURL=http://envoygateway
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
      - "6000:443"
    depends_on:
      - envoygateway
      - firstapi
      - secondapi
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
    networks:
      - test-net-1


volumes:
  reservationdb:
  reservationapi:  

networks:
  test-net-1:
    driver: bridge
    external: true
```

this is my docker-compose.override.yaml. And I want to send Get request to my Reservation (firstapi)
and I have written this code for this :

```cs
public async Task<List<ReservationDto>> GetAllReservation()
        {
            string envoyGatewayUrl = "https://host.docker.internal:10001/r";
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(envoyGatewayUrl);
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ReservationDto>>(content);
        }
```

and this variant worked but I get this error :

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.GetFrameSize(ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
```

and I tried before envoyGatewayUrl : http://envoygateway:10001 , http://localhost:10001 , http://envoygateway but all of them is not working. How can I correct this code.
Note: I tried this command : dotnet dev-certs https --trust and my envoy work well
Thank for your attention :)

I have envoy gateway and I want to send request from my blazor app to envoy and envoy work as gateway.
this is my envoy.yaml :

```yaml
admin:
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 9902
static_resources:

  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 10000
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          access_log:
          - name: envoy.access_loggers.stdout
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.stream.v3.StdoutAccessLog
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/r"
                route:
                  prefix_rewrite: "/reservation"
                  cluster: reservation_service
              - match:
                  prefix: "/e"
                route:
                  prefix_rewrite: "/email"
                  cluster: email_service
  clusters:
  - name: reservation_service
    type: LOGICAL_DNS
    # Comment out the following line to test on v6 networks
    dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: reservation_service
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: firstapi
                port_value: 80
  - name: email_service
    type: LOGICAL_DNS
    # Comment out the following line to test on v6 networks
    dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: email_service
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: secondapi
                port_value: 80
```